# Moving code behind xaml.cs to ViewModel in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, viewmodel, code-behind

I have coded my behind code logic in xaml.cs file and now i want to move my code from code behind to ViewModel. How can this be done apart from code refactoring.

I am new to xamarin

Here is my Code behind

```
namespace _somename
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CareingtonFeeSchedule : ContentPage
    {

        private OneDentalFeeScheduleService oneDentalFeeScheduleService;
        private ObservableCollection<ProviderSearchViewModel> _allGroups;
        private ObservableCollection<ProviderSearchViewModel> _expandedGroups;

        protected ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, FeeScheduleItem>> feeScheduleGroups;
        protected ObservableCollection<FeeScheduleItem> feeScheduleItems;

        private readonly AppViewModel AppViewModelInstance;
        private Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position currentPosition;

        private FeeScheduleModel feeScheduleDataResult;
        public CareingtonFeeSchedule(AppViewModel appViewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AppViewModelInstance = appViewModel;

            BindingContext = AppViewModelInstance;
            AppViewModelInstance.IsActivityLoading = true;
            LoadFeeeSchedule();
        }

        private void HeaderTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            int selectedIndex = _expandedGroups.IndexOf(
                ((ProviderSearchViewModel)((Button)sender).CommandParameter));
            _allGroups[selectedIndex].Expanded = !_allGroups[selectedIndex].Expanded;
            UpdateListContent();
        }

        async Task OnHomeFeeScheduleTapped_TappedAsync(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new AccLandPage(AppViewModelInstance));
        }

        private void ProviderBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var keyword = ProviderSearchBar.Text;

            GroupedView.ItemsSource =
                                _expandedGroups.Where(s =>
                s.Title.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()));
        }

        private void UpdateListContent()
        {
            _expandedGroups = new ObservableCollection<ProviderSearchViewModel>();
            foreach (ProviderSearchViewModel group in _allGroups)
            {
                ProviderSearchViewModel newGroup = new ProviderSearchViewModel(group.Title, group.ShortName, group.Expanded);
                if (group.Expanded)
                {
                    foreach (Plan plan in group)
                    {
                        newGroup.Add(plan);
                    }
                }
                _expandedGroups.Add(newGroup);
            }
            GroupedView.ItemsSource = _expandedGroups;
        }

        public FeeScheduleModel FeeScheduleDataResult
        {
            protected set
            {
                feeScheduleDataResult = value;

                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FeeScheduleDataResult));
            }

            get => feeScheduleDataResult;
        }

        protected int feeScheduleCount;
        public int FeeScheduleCount => feeScheduleCount;

        private async Task<bool> LoadFeeeSchedule()
        {

            try
            {
                if (oneDentalFeeScheduleService == null)
                {
                    oneDentalFeeScheduleService = new OneDentalFeeScheduleService("1dental.com");
                }
                var feeSchedRes = await oneDentalFeeScheduleService.GetFeeScheduleAsync(AppViewModelInstance.ZipCode, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);

                if (feeSchedRes?.Schedule?.Count > 0)
                {

                    ConvertFeeScheuleDict(feeSchedRes.Schedule);
                }
                else FeeScheduleDataResult = null;

                return true;

            }
            catch (Exception eX)
            {
               with the fee schedule lookup: \n{eX.Message}", "OK");


                return false;
            }
            finally
            {

                AppViewModelInstance.IsActivityLoading = false;
                actInd.IsRunning = false;
            }
        }

        private void ConvertFeeScheuleDict(Dictionary<string, List<FeeScheduleItem>> feesche)
        {

            ObservableCollection<ProviderSearchViewModel> list = new ObservableCollection<ProviderSearchViewModel>();

            ProviderSearchViewModel psm = null;

            foreach (var item in feesche)
            {
                psm = new ProviderSearchViewModel(item.Key, "");

                foreach (var valitem in item.Value)
                {
                    Plan p = new Plan();
                    p.Code = valitem.Code;
                    p.CostDisplay = valitem.CostDisplay;
                    p.Description = valitem.ProcedureSecondary;
                    p.Name = valitem.Procedure;

                    psm.Add(p);
                }

                list.Add(psm);
            }

            _allGroups = list;

            UpdateListContent();

        }

        private async void GetZipCode()
        {
            try
            {   

                if (AppViewModelInstance.UserPosition == null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var hasPermission = await Utils.CheckPermissions(Permission.Location);
                        if (!hasPermission)
                        {

                            await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainScreen());

                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        Debug.WriteLine($"Exception occurred while looking permission during Appearing event: {ex}");
                    }                                      

                    var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;


                    currentPosition = await locator.GetPositionAsync(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10, 0));

                    var addressList = await locator.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(currentPosition, null);

                    AppViewModelInstance.UserPosition = currentPosition;


                    foreach (var item in addressList)
                    {
                        AppViewModelInstance.ZipCode = item.PostalCode;
                        ZipCodeEntry.Text = item.PostalCode;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
                    currentPosition = AppViewModelInstance.UserPosition;
                    var addressList = await locator.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(currentPosition, null);
                    foreach (var item in addressList)
                    {
                        AppViewModelInstance.ZipCode = item.PostalCode;
                        ZipCodeEntry.Text = item.PostalCode;
                        break;
                    }
                }                

                LoadFeeeSchedule();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Exception occurred while looking up location during Appearing event: {ex}");
            }

        }

        private void ZipCodeEntry_Complete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != null)
            {
                AppViewModelInstance.ZipCode = ((Entry)sender).Text;
            }
        }

        private void ZipCodeEntry_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != null)
            {
                string _text = ((Entry)sender).Text;      //Get Current Text

                if (_text.Length > 5)       //If it is more than your character restriction
                {
                    _text = _text.Remove(_text.Length - 1);  // Remove Last character

                    ZipCodeEntry.Text = _text;        //Set the Old value               
                }

                if (_text.Length == 5)
                {
                    AppViewModelInstance.ZipCode = _text;
                    LoadFeeeSchedule();   
                }
            }
        }

        public bool CanRefreshExecute(string tempVal = null)
        {
            if (AppViewModelInstance.IsRefreshing) return false;
            var valToCheck = tempVal ?? AppViewModelInstance.ZipCode;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valToCheck) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valToCheck)) return false;

            bool isDigitString = true;
            foreach (var c in valToCheck)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(c)) continue;
                isDigitString = false;
            }

            if (isDigitString) AppViewModelInstance.ZipCode = valToCheck;

            return isDigitString;
        }

        private void GroupedView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {

        }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just export your code to the view model and set the view model as binding context of the Page. For example in the constructor:

```
//In the code behind
PageViewModel viewModel;

public Page()
{
    this.BindingContext = viewModel = new PageViewModel();

//...
}
```

The ViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

(Functions which are triggered by events have to stay in the code behind and access the view model through the ViewModel Property)

Comment: The ViewModel does implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Will you guide me as to how to export my code to ViewModel as i am very new to this kind of learning.

Comment: @UtkarshNadgouda with export I meant  move your code. Sry my bad

Comment: Moving the code entirely i.e copy pasting my .xaml.cs code to viewmodel.cs file?

Comment: Yeah kind of.. Copy all functions and properties you want to export.